# Sanitization of register_setting()

Tags: plugin-development, sanitization

How to do sanitization at `register_setting()` ?

I am learning Plugin Development. I am using below code.

```php
public function settings_page_registration() {
    register_setting(
        'sports_info_api_key',
        'wp_api_key',
        array(
            'type' => 'string',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
        )
    ); 
}
```

How can I move forward ? What should I write inside `sanitize_text_field` function if I would like to receive only text value ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sanitize_text_field` exactly as you are. From [the function's documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/):

> - Checks for invalid UTF-8,
> - Converts single < characters to entities
> - Strips all tags
> - Removes line breaks, tabs, and extra whitespace
> - Strips percent-encoded characters

[`sanitize_text_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/) is already defined as a function in WordPress, so you don't need to change anything. The `sanitize_callback` parameter takes a function name; only if you want to do custom sanitization would you need to define a new function.